# How to specify typescript function return interface based on the input?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Itest {
  a: { a: number };
  b: { b: number };
  c: { c: number };
  d: { d: number };
}

type Tname = keyof Itest;

interface Isdk {
    init: (
        dep: Tname[],
        param: (<T extends Tname, K = Itest[T]>(name: T) => K | undefined) | Itest[Tname]
    ) => void;
}

const SDK: Isdk = {
    init: (dep, param) => {},
};

SDK.init(['a'], (name) => {
    if (name === 'a') {
        return {
            a: 1,
        };
    }
    if (name === 'b') {
        return {
            a: 1,
        };
    }
    if (name === 'c') {
        return {
            a: 1,
        };
    }
    if (name === 'd') {
        return {
            a: 1,
        };
    }
    return;
});
```

I want to define the return interface based on the input, for example if the name is a, then the return value must be `{ a: number }`. The above attempt is not working.

Comment: May I refactor your code to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/weQvKw)?  Other than naming conventions (especially the `K` being used for a non-keylike type, which is certainly unconventional), the big change here is that I've removed the second generic type parameter whose job seems to be just copying the result of `Itest[T]`.  Assuming you agree that this demonstrates the same problem, I'd say that you've hit a TS limitation; you can't generate indexed access types by if/else this way, see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014). ...

Comment: ...  If you want this to work you could rewrite it so that your indexed access type corresponds to an actual indexing operation, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/weQvKw). Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me.)

Comment: @jcalz the code block u posted has the same error `Type '{ a: number; b?: undefined; c?: undefined; d?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Test[K]'`

Comment: `an actual indexing operation` i think this could be acceptable

Comment: altho the reason why we have a function in where we can return value is that we can try to implement async / await (Promise<T>).

Comment: Sorry, wrong link.  It should have said "actual indexing operation like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVbjlN)".  Does that work?  Note how the implementation is an index into an object whose properties are implemented as accessor methods.

Comment: @jcalz yes, and i think this could work for the async / await as well. Sweet.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you check a value `name` of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `K` via `if (name === "a") {return {a: 1}}`, this [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of `name`, *but currently it does not narrow or re-constrain the type `K` itself*.

You are supposed to return a value of the generic [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) type `Test[K]`, but when you `return {a: 1}`, the compiler can't verify that this is appropriate.  If `K` could be narrowed/constrained to `"a"`, then `Test[K]` could be computed as `Test["a"]` which is `{a: number}`, and then `{a: 1}` would be accepted.  But this does not happen, and so you get a compiler error.

The same holds true for all your other checks `if (name === "b")`, et cetera.

This is a limitation of TypeScript, and there are a number of open feature requests in GitHub asking for some improvement here.  If [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) are ever implemented, it might make your code compile as-is.

But as of TypeScript 4.9, it's not part of the language.

---

For now, if you want to return a value of a generic indexed access type like `Test[K]` in a way that the compiler can verify as safe, the best approach is to *actually perform an indexing operation*, like `return test[name]` where `test` is of type `Test` and `name` is of type `K`.

You have `name` already in your function. Let's refactor so that we can also provide `test`:

```
SDK.init(['a'], (name) => {
  const test: Test = {
    get a() { return { a: 1 } },
    get b() { return { b: 1 } },
    get c() { return { c: 1 } },
    get d() { return { d: 1 } }
  }
  return test[name];
}); // okay
```

The variable `test` is an object of type `Test`.  Each property is implemented as [a getter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), so that at runtime only the property you actually care about will be computed.

And this compiles successfully, because `test[name]` is known to be of type `Test[K]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyycAXLieSAK4C2ARtMgL4Dchx95OyXyNDJmw7IE3UVTqMoLdkWQATcUv5Shc5oS0FQkWIhQBlBQGtcI0MDDkAFCOIKIAB1smIATwD2MNJjABKAG0AXQAae2QnOCg4WlsAHgBpZAgAD0gQBQxkNy8fdCwAPhsQWIhyRP9kAF5C3yxAxODkAB9kakyIGFAIBSq2grBA3O96sGCRKtrkADdPYAUNbQRPECxkQwARRPJjM2rzeUtrZBtHJ1DI6Nipup5mcIJhAkItxIA6Y5tAgHI4H7Cp1KtAgt0OxBWa2wkCw5EGNXBxGQAHMINg4DYqjwoGjqFAQBQyMgAIwsFiPJEotG8TEUHFgPEEnh8UnMckRVHYBC07G4-EUMQkskPDnUhQ85D0xkUFSslgiTTyKX8mFDYEQYIafxyQhAA)